# Trouble shooting with Complextype

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a complextype-'A' that uses a extension base-'Base' followed a sequence of elements. Now the extension base-'Base' is complextype itself and has multiple elements references in a sequence ex.(Element 1,2,3). The problem i am have is that when trying to validate the XML the error i get is the Element 'A' has invalid child '1' and it list the other possible elements on the XML. i can only make changes to the schema not the XML since im working in a group. Sry if i explained it weird example will be below

This is the schema

```
<xsd:complexType name="A">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Base" >
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:complexContent>
                                <xsd:extension base="BData"/>
                            </xsd:complexContent>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="C" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:complexContent>
                                <xsd:extension base="CData"/>
                            </xsd:complexContent>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="D" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:complexContent>
                                <xsd:extension base="DData"/>
                            </xsd:complexContent>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

The XML

```
<A>
  <D/>
  <B/>
  <C/>
  <T>     <---- This is the element from the base'Base' that gives me the error>
   <......>
  </T>
</A>
```

OK so after seeing the comments I'm going to elaborate a little more on my question. This is my first time posting a question and the issue I'm facing is related to my job so i cant post specific details. So the main problem is with 'A'. So i have the Schema I'm editing that suppose to validate multiple XML. So the goal is for me to find a way for the Complextype A to have each element valid but at the same time if a element is called form the extension that no matter the order or number of times an error wont popup. I have done researched the 'all' element but the problem with that is that it can only occur 1 time. Conclusion: Sequence unlimited number of Occur but order restricted, All no order restriction but limited to 1 Occurrence. This is like a rabbit hole of problems any solutions is welcomed.

Comment: XML element names cannot begin with a number.

Comment: You're missing a closing `xsd:sequence` element.

Comment: You've not included the referenced `Base` declaration.

Comment: Your formatting is a mess.

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and return with a proper *[mcve]*.    Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, all complex-type extensions create a sequence whose first member is the complex type as defined in the base type, and whose second member is the content model given in the extension.  The guarantee to consumers of the base type is then that if they read the beginning of the element, they will find what they need there, and when they start to see children they are not prepared for, they can stop reading.  (Or, more formally:  in any valid instance I of the extended type E, there is a prefix of the sequence of children of I which is valid against the base type of E.)

In XSD 1.1, it is also possible to extend an all-group with another all-group and have the result be (as many people said they wanted) a larger all-group; sequences and choices, though, work the same as in XSD 1.0.

So the problem with your instance is that it has an element allowed by the base type after, instead of before, the elements allowed by your extension.  If you want that to be legal in your type A, then the relation between A and Base is not one of type extension, and you'll have to define it some other way.